# Ubuntu 18.04: Error with mailx smtp - mailx: unrecognized option "-S'"?

Tags: ubuntu, smtp, mailx

I was trying to send an email to multiple persons using `mailx` (mailx (GNU Mailutils) 3.4). I did that successfully on a previous version of Ubuntu, v16.04, and the script was working fine. Now I have Ubuntu 18.04 and the following problem:

```
mailx: unrecognized option -S
mailx: unrecognized option -S
mailx: unrecognized option -S
```

what should I do?

My script is as follow:

```
#!/bin/bash
FILE="speakers.csv"
while IFS=";" read name mailAdress
do
     printf "Dear $name, \n\n something something... "  | mailx -s "Title" -S smtp=smtps://mySMPTadress -S smtp-auth=login -S smtp-auth-user="MyUserName" -S smtp-auth-password='MyPassword' -S from="MyName <MyEmailAdress>"  mailAdress
done < "$FILE"
```

file speakers.csv looks like this

```
Klaus A;klaus@*****.de
Alessandra B;alessandra@****.it
Serge C;serge@****.fr
```

Comment: DId you try `mail` instead of `mailx`? maybe deprecated!

Comment: Thanks for the acceptance, favour returned: Question upvoted!  **;-)** (For my curiosity: which solution did you take?)

Comment: Whoever tooks the decision to break everything like that, deserve to get ban from the internet. It's broken AF and nothing changed in 10 years.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Quick and dirty:**

`mailx` is a link to `s-nail` so you should use `s-nail` instead as according to its [Bionic man page](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/bionic/man1/s-nail.1.html) it still has the `-S` option.

**Do it properly:**

You should avoid sending mail like that because anyone that has access to `ps` can read your password as it's on the command line and you should look into using the `-A` (account) option to store this in the `.netrc` file that only the user and root have access to. (Read the full [man page](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/bionic/man1/s-nail.1.html))

Answer (score 5):

Debian and Ubuntu have replaced Heirloom `mailx` with s-nail `mailx`.  Both support that option.  But there are several other `mailx` commands from other packages which do not, including the GNU Mailutils `mailx` which you have apparently unknowingly switched to.

On the gripping hand, as Fabby said, do not pass user credentials around in command arguments (or environment variables).

## Further reading

- [`mailx`](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/xenial/en/man1/mailx.1posix.html).  Ubuntu 16.04 manual pages.
- [`mailx`](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/xenial/man1/heirloom-mailx.1.html).  Ubuntu 16.04 manual pages.
- [`mailx`](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/xenial/man1/bsd-mailx.1.html).  Ubuntu 16.04 manual pages.
- [`mailx`](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/trusty/man1/heirloom-mailx.1.html).  Ubuntu 14.04 manual pages.
- [`s-nail`](https://manpages.debian.org/stretch/s-nail/s-nail.1.en.html).  User commands.  s-nail.  Debian manual pages.
- [`mailx`](https://manpages.debian.org/stretch/mailutils/mailx.1.en.html).  User commands.  GNU mail utils.  Debian manual pages.
- [`mailx`](https://manpages.debian.org/stretch/bsd-mailx/mailx.1.en.html).  General Commands Manual.  BSD mailx.  Debian manual pages.
- [`mailx`](https://manpages.debian.org/stretch/nmh/mailx.1.en.html).  User commands.  NMH.  Debian manual pages.
- [Difference between mail and mailx?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/89530/)

Comment: **+1** just for using *on the gripping hand*.  (also: I wasn't aware that OP switched to GNU mail utils...) **¯\\_(ツ)_/¯**